# Drupal fboauth module - how to get the friendlist of a user

Tags: social-network

I have checked the friendlist field in configuration settings of the fboauth module. Now what do I do to get the friend list of the logged in user.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know $access_token.

```
$result = fboauth_graph_query('me/friends', $access_token);
```

See the Facebook API for a list of commands: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/